# how can I show this combination with select?

Tags: laravel, combinations

models structure it looks like the following

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function attribute_options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeOption::class);
    }
}

class AttributeOption extends Model
{
    public function attribute_option()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CombinationDetail::class);
    }

    public function attribute(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
    }
}

class Combination extends Model
{
    public function combination_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CombinationDetail::class);
    }
}

class CombinationDetail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['attribute_options_id'];

    public function attribute_options()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AttributeOption::class);
    }
}
```

Relationship models like this.

[combination table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHmXi.png)

[combination_details table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tWjn.png)

how can i show this with selectbox or div with javascript

Comment: What do you mean by 'this'? What is the data you want to show and what is an example?

Comment: this combination for e commerce site product select

Comment: @GoogleMac https://www.vistaprint.com/business-cards/rounded-corner?txi=18224&xnid=TopNav_Rounded+corner_Premium+shapes_Business+Cards&xnav=TopNav example site select combination